# how to merge partitions on Ubuntu?

Tags: partitioning

I had Ubuntu 18.04 on my laptop(150 GB root , 30 GB home,dual-boot with windows 10).
I just reinstall Ubuntu 18.04 on my laptop and I used default installation but my previous home became a partition(dev/sda4) and my new Ubuntu is installed with its own home directory in 150GB space, I want to merge dev/sda4 and  my main Ubuntu partition without data loss, how can I do it?

Comment: Although many commercial partition management utilities claim so, partitions are never merged, one is removed and other is expanded, with or without moving depending on the case. Please boot a live session, open GParted and post a screenshot of your drive and then explain how you want it to look like so we can think about the best method to achieve the intended result.

Comment: The wording of the question is confusing. Do you have two Ubuntu root partitions? Or do you have three partitions, two are / and one is /home? Or there are two / and two /home partitions? Please reword/clarify your question and post a screenshot of your drive in GParted so we can help you further.